# Undefined variable and mysqli errors

Tags: php, html, mysqli, compiler-errors

I get those errors in my code and i don't know why

**ERRORS**:

```
1. Undefined variable: con in /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/SE/index.php on line 28
 2. mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/SE/index.php on line 28
 3. Undefined variable: con in /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/SE/index.php on line 29
 4. mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/SE/index.php on line 29
 5. Undefined variable: con in /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/SE/index.php on line 31
 6. mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/SE/index.php on line 31
 7. mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/SE/index.php on line 32
 8. mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/SE/index.php on line 33
```

here are my files

**dbcon.php**

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "login";

function getConnected($hostname, $username, $password, $database) {
        $con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

        if($con->connect_error)
            die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
return $con;}?>
```

**index.php**

```html
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php include('dbcon.php');?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="form-wrapper">
  
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <h3>Влез в системата</h3>
 
    <div class="form-item">
  <input type="text" name="user" required="required" placeholder="Фак. Номер" autofocus required/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-item">
  <input type="password" name="pass" required="required" placeholder="Парола" required/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="button-panel">
  <input type="submit" class="button" title="Log In" name="login" value="Влез"/>
    </div>
  </form>
  <?php
 if (isset($_POST['login']))
  {
   $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user']);
   $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass']);
        
   $query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE  password='$password' and username='$username'");
   $row  = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
   $num_row  = mysqli_num_rows($query);
   
   if ($num_row > 0) 
    {   
     $_SESSION['user_id']=$row['user_id'];
     header('location:home.php');
     
    }
   else
    {
     echo 'Invalid Username and Password Combination';
    }
  }
  ?>
  <div class="reminder">
    <p>Not a member? <a href="#">Sign up now</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get those errors for the mysqli_query(), mysqli_fetch_array() and mysqli_num_rows(). They all expect parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in.

Comment: you never call your `getConnected` function. use `$con=getConnected();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `dbcon.php` file you have a function `getConnected($hostname, $username, $password, $database)` but you are never using it. You should in your code in **index.php** do something like:

```
$con = getConnected($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
```

and it will look like follows:

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $con = getConnected($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass']);
    // ........ rest of your code
```

Or you can those lines write out of a function:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

        if($con->connect_error) // should be mysqli_connect_errno()
            die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
return $con; // without return
```

so **dbcon.php** would look like this:

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "login";

$con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

if($con->connect_error) // should be mysqli_connect_errno()
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
```

Also in your function (**dbcon.php**) checking if connection is established is wrote wrong, it should be like follows:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

You are using **Procedural style**, more informations can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: If i do it with $con = new getConnected(); i get that error Fatal error: Class 'getConnected' not found in /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/SE/index.php on line 27

Comment: Sorry, made some misspell :D Check my answer please again :)

Comment: I get still errors ;D for missing arguments and for undefined variables in dbcon.php (hostname, username, password, database)

Comment: Check now please ;)

Comment: Ye i notice that error but now i have mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/SE/dbcon.php on line 8 and Trying to get property of non-object in /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/SE/dbcon.php on line 10

Comment: You are wrong checking errors, I have updated my answer. In if should be not `$con->connect_error` but `mysqli_connect_errno()`. About second error it says that you are giving wrong data to connect to your server.

Comment: Ye i know that its for wrong date, but where i can find whats the password for the root? Or how can i fix this error?

Comment: While you are creating your SQL server you write data which you use to login f.ex. in phpmyadmin. It is the same data. Also table name you can find after you login to phpmyadmin. Right now I've fixed your problem and about searching login data I think it is a new kind of problem, so you should create a new question and accept my answer :) Thanks!

Comment: Ye thanks for the help man. I will try to fix it alone if i can't i will post a new problem ;)